# Crash while upgrading to Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: upgrade, updates, 16.04, crash

I was upgrading my Ubuntu 14.04 to 16.04 LTS using the command

```
sudo update-manager -d
```

The process had finished downloading the packages and was in the process of installation. Some thing like 60% of the installation was done.

I was not present on my desk and after sometime when I returned, the system had crashed. It was giving some lines like ...

```
... snip a lot of similar lines

[   7.309480] systemd-journald[259]: Failed to open runtime Journal. No data available
... snip a lot of similar lines
```

Some background. I had a custom kernel where I had added 1-2 system calls, and put that in the startup I think.

---

So, what I did was during boot, I went to the advance options and chose the older normal kernel (not the custom one), then the system booted, but it wasn't showing the right utility bar, and neither was the terminal opening. I tried resetin `unity`, but it gets stuck in `opengl` line.

Help please.